# Find the position of numbers in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have following strings where I need to know position of data by specific characters.

Isaiah Kinney 06/2021 **1**11111

Darius Knox 10/2020 **1**11-334-555

Leo Wiley 07/2020 **1**22-333

Stone Walls 11/2020 **2**112333

John Stone 12/2021 **x**xx-xx-xxx

I need to know on which positions are number marked as bold, when I don't have numbers instead of them I have x chars.

I tried with this " (\d+(\d+|-*)\d+)( |$)" but with this I have whitespace before bold number.

Comment: This was closed a bit fast, here was the answer I was writing while someone else closed it.

On each line there are 3 columns
   - a name
   - a date 
   - a code (either numbers or x separated by dashes).

Your data match this "regular expression" pattern:

^(?<name>.+) (?<date>\d+\/\d+) (?<code>[0-9x]+(?:-[0-9x]+)*)$
   

^ marks the start of a line

$ marks he end of a line

In between you have the three groups
 name, date and code. 

https://regex101.com/r/2Xu0Jh/1

Comment: Thank you @Pascal Ganaye for your answer, your patter match whole string, how to match only with data in last column code?

Comment: This is the end of  the pattern:

 (?<code>[0-9x]+(?:-[0-9x]+)*)$

This will match only the last part (note that it starts with a space).
The syntax differs a bit depending of your language, but generally matches[0] will return the whole capture group with the space and matches[1] or matches["code"] will return only the capture group you want.

Comment: @Maxt8r there is no need Ryszard Czech solution is ok for me and working, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(?<!\S)(?:x+(?:-x+)*|\d+(?:-\d+)*)$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/pvCkVP/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    x+                       'x' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      x+                       'x' (1 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

[Code](https://ideone.com/jfEDDF) generated by regex101 seems to yield the expected details:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<!\S)(?:x+(?:-x+)*|\d+(?:-\d+)*)$";
        string input = @"Isaiah Kinney 06/2021 111111
Darius Knox 10/2020 111-334-555
Leo Wiley 07/2020 122-333
Stone Walls 11/2020 2112333
John Stone 12/2021 xxx-xx-xxx";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
 
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'111111' found at index 22.
'111-334-555' found at index 49.
'122-333' found at index 79.
'2112333' found at index 107.
'xxx-xx-xxx' found at index 134.
```